# Ubuntu 16.04 suddenly restarting after 10 or 15 minutes

Tags: 16.04

It has been few weeks which I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and it was working perfectly fine but today I faced problem which during my work it just restarted suddenly. I am actually using dual boot with Windows 8 and when I tried to relogin through the boot menu after selecting ubuntu a black screen appeared and then another page that was written recoving journal... something like cleaning orphaned files....

The same thing happened few times during my work around 10 - 15 minutes...

Comment: I have clearly noticed that it is shutting completely down not restarting so any idea please !!!

Comment: Ubuntu DOES NOT HAVE a 'poweroff-without-warning' feature...but your motherboard does. You have all the symptoms of hardware failure. Use your favorite search engine to learn how to disassemble your machine and check the power supply, fans, and motherboard.

Comment: I am Ghafar... My system is configured dual both (Ubuntu / Windows 8) but when I am using windows for days there is no shutdown but just few days back when I was using Ubuntu (working on packettracer) the system was shutted down automatically 2 or 3 times after 15 - 20 minutes. I am sure there is something but have no idea why...

After turning on the system it was displaying something like Cleaning Orphaned files, UID 1000, GID. ETC / or sometimes Recovery Journal....

Comment: Orphaned inodes are a classic symptom of hardware-caused poweroff. 2-or-3-times in 15 to 20 minutes seems like a thermal failure. Try using Windows very intensively, and you are likely to get the same result.